# Is there any official Android support library as replacement for Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator

Tags: android

I am big fan of Jake Wharthon's libraries - ActionBarSherlock, NineOldAndroids and [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator)

My app does support Android 2.3.3 and above.

Since I need to port my app from holo to material design, yet to support existing 2.3.3 customers, I already replace `ActionBarSherlock` with `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

I was planning to move away from `ViewPagerIndicator` too, as the project doesn't get any update since 3 years ago. I prefer to have something exactly from Google's support library.

Although I still love how `ViewPagerIndicator` looks like

1. It has a very thin height, which doesn't take away much screen asset.
2. It only show 3 titles (Left, middle, right) at any given time. Not more than that. This looks clean.

I was wondering, is there any official Android support library as replacement for Jake Wharton's `ViewPagerIndicator`?

Comment: Library provide by Jake Wharthon is great...you can check http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html   this will work for tab and page title but not sure whether it will work with image feature as provided by Jake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Although I still love how ViewPagerIndicator looks like

There are many indicators in that library.

> is there any official Android support library as replacement for Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator?

No, other than for tabs, where the Design Support library offers [`TabLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html).